# SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'starting_balance' doesn't have a default value

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I am getting a very bizarre "Field doesn't have a default value" error. The field in question is `starting_balance`. It seems that Laravel is trying to save the `starting_balance` field into the database as if it was empty but I am sure it isn't. Any help appreciated.

I tried adding a default value for the field in the migration but that still doesn't help.

Here is my migration for the model:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateApartmentsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('apartments', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('entrance_id');
            $table->integer('user_id')->nullable()->default(null);
            $table->integer('floor');
            $table->integer('apt_number');
            $table->string('square_meters', 64)->nullable();
            $table->decimal('percent_ideal_parts', 10, 3)->nullable();
            $table->decimal('starting_balance', 8, 2);
            $table->string('animals', 200)->nullable();
            $table->string('other_information', 2048)->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('apartments');
    }
}
```

Here is the relevant part from the controller handling the request:

```
public function store(Request $request, ApartmentRequest $apartmentRequest)
{
    $apartment = new Apartment($request->except(['obekt_id', '_token']));

    if ($apartment->save())
    {
        Session::flash('success', 'Апартамента беше запазен успешно.');
        return redirect('/entrances/' . $apartment->entrance->id . '/apartments');
    }
    else
    {
        Session::flash('error', 'Имаше проблем докато запазвахме апартамента.');
        return back();
    }
}
```

Here is my model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Apartment extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['entrance_id', 'user_id', 'floor', 'apt_number', 'square_meters', 'percent_ideal_parts', 'starting_balance', 'animals', 'other_information'];

    public function people()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Person');
    }

    public function entrance()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Entrance');
    }

    public function taksiDomoupravitel()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\TaksaDomoupravitel');
    }

    public function taksiFro()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\TaksaFro');
    }

    public function payments()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Payment');
    }

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
}
```

Here is a dd of the $request->except('obekt_id', '_token') part:

```
array:9 [▼
  "entrance_id" => "1"
  "user_id" => null
  "floor" => "15"
  "apt_number" => "15"
  "square_meters" => null
  "percent_ideal_parts" => "15"
  "starting_balance" => "-20"
  "animals" => null
  "other_information" => null
]
```

Here is my ApartmentRequest validation class:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use App\Rules\UniqueFloorAndAptNumber;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class ApartmentRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'obekt_id' => 'required|exists:obekti,id',
            'entrance_id' => 'required|exists:entrances,id',
            'user_id' => 'exists:users,id|nullable',
            'floor' => ['required', 'numeric', new UniqueFloorAndAptNumber],
            'apt_number' => ['required', 'numeric', new UniqueFloorAndAptNumber],
            'percent_ideal_parts' => 'required|numeric',
            'starting_balance' => 'required|numeric',
            'animals' => 'max:200',
            'other_information' => 'max:2048',
        ];
    }
}
```

here is the blade view part for the starting balance field:

```
<div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('starting_balance') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
    <label for="starting_balance" class="col-md-4 control-label red-text">Моля въведете начално салдо *</label>

    <div class="col-md-6">
        <input id="starting_balance" type="text" class="form-control" name="starting_balance" value="{{ old('starting_balance') }}">

        @if ($errors->has('starting_balance'))
            <span class="help-block">
                <strong>{{ $errors->first('starting_balance') }}</strong>
            </span>
        @endif
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The starting balance could be empty in your request. It's hard to tell. You could always set it to nullable, or add a default value of 0.

Comment: Can you print request and add to question? and try this on migration. `$table->decimal('starting_balance', 8, 2)->nullable();`

Comment: For Preventing this kind of problem you should use laravel validation rules.

Comment: @akcoban I've added a print of the request, I also tried nullable() but it didn't work

Comment: @Md.SukelAli I am using validation, just added it to the question

Comment: @aynber I tried both didn't work

Comment: @UdhavSarvaiya I commented on your answer

Comment: Are your validation rules working? 
Have you tried with wrong data? 
Are the errors showing? 
i can't see your validation call -> `$ApartmentRequest ->validate([]);`

Comment: @EmmanuelHdzDíaz Validation is working. The request is automatically validated when you put ApartmentRequest as parameter of the controller method.

Comment: @Petar Vasilev i've recreated all your model, and there is no error, it saves fine.
Can we see your DB structure please?

Comment: And please, upload a picture of your error.

Comment: @EmmanuelHdzDíaz here is the screenshot: https://imgur.com/a/2KDTUpP

Comment: @EmmanuelHdzDíaz here is a pastebin of the database sql: https://pastebin.com/9xUXuw1C

Comment: @Petar Vasilev Ok, You're not sending a value to `starting_balance` in your error image you can see the data sent: (1,null,17,17,null,17,null,null,null), perhaps you have a error in your form! check the `starting_balance` field name. We haven't see that code yet.

Comment: @EmmanuelHdzDíaz but when I print the request data it's in it!

Comment: @EmmanuelHdzDíaz I've added the blade view part for the field in question

Comment: @Petar Vasilev What prints `dd` with `$apartmentRequest`?

Comment: @EmmanuelHdzDíaz here is a dd of the $apartmentRequest: https://pastebin.com/pAmWBgXT

Comment: @Petar Vasilev I can't figured out your error, the last thing i can suggest is to put this code: `$apartment -> starting_balance = $request -> starting_balance;` after:  `$apartment = new Apartment($request->except(['obekt_id', '_token']));`

Comment: @EmmanuelHdzDíaz that actually solved it... : ) I wonder what's causing it though?

Comment: @Petar Vasilev I don't have any idea! haha, but at leat your problem is solved

Comment: @EmmanuelHdzDíaz you can post an answer if you want, I'll accept it

Answer (score 0):

The error is pretty clear: `starting_balance` doesn't have a default value.

You can update your migration file by adding a default value like so:

```
// if you want to set 0 as default value
$table->decimal('starting_balance', 8, 2)->default(0);

// if you want to set NULL as default value
$table->decimal('starting_balance', 8, 2)->nullable();
```

Comment: I tried both, in neither case did the value got saved in the database.

Comment: did you run `php artisan migrate:fresh` to drop and re-create all the tables?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, i got your problem,
you validate ApartmentRequest $apartmentRequest but use Request $request
Your code should be looks like this

```
public function store(ApartmentRequest $apartmentRequest)
{
    $apartment = new Apartment($apartmentRequest->except(['obekt_id', '_token']));

    if ($apartment->save())
    {
        Session::flash('success', 'Апартамента беше запазен успешно.');
        return redirect('/entrances/' . $apartment->entrance->id . '/apartments');
    }
    else
    {
        Session::flash('error', 'Имаше проблем докато запазвахме апартамента.');
        return back();
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks the same what did you change. Anyway, afaik, the right way is to use Request $request

Comment: As you are created a custom request (ApartmentRequest ) class for handling validation so you have to use it. Unless your validation rules is not going to apply. So, when you use general Request class in store method your rules are not going to apply.

Comment: And i change something look closely to your method parameters and this line,

$apartment = new Apartment($apartmentRequest->except(['obekt_id', '_token']));

Comment: I am using both

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`$apartment -> starting_balance = $request -> starting_balance;`

After:

`$apartment = new Apartment($request->except(['obekt_id', '_token']));`